# Using JBOSS FUSE for Proxying Huge amount of webservices

Tags: web-services, esb, jbossfuse

I am proxing huge amount of web services using JBOSS FUSE ESB.

using content based router for deciding the real web services. But, If there is a new services deployed in backend. I am forced to change the proxy details (WSDL) and expose the interface.

which leads to client regenerate the client code again.

Is there any other solution which will allow me to optimize this problem in design level.

Comment: See my answer below how many web services are you talking about? Show us some code as well like how you do the content based routing etc. Bit difficult to answer like this.

Comment: Your answer looks optimized and good.

Answer (score 1):

Some general thoughts on this but I would need more detail to give some solid advise.

You are proxing the services thus you are not abstracting the services away. You are exposing the services rather directly to the outside via the service on FuseESB.

Typically you would use a ESB to abstract provider and consumers away from each other. This means that you wont expose/proxy the service directly. For example you would create generic operations and data structures. This will allow you to then map the generic interface to the web service implementation that you are providing.

Another approach would be to version the different WSDL's and thus have different versions of the services out there. This will allow you to have client consume the older WSDL's and then migrate them over bit by bit.

Comment: Do you mean, the generic method which client sees must be accepting Request of interface or abstract class. so that all of its child can be passed (Provided all the service request inherits this interface/abstract class) to the JBOSS FUSE and we can decide the real service based on the content we receive. Is my understanding right???

Comment: Yes more or less. I would suggest you look at some of the SOAP protocol standards such as IFX, OFX and others to gain a understanding of how to abstract a web service so you dont expose providers directly to consumers and end up with tightly coupled classes.

Comment: Ofx is a open source standard. Head over to the oasis website and download some xsd there.